# Error when posting on facebook using the share dialog method

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I tried putting up a facebook post from my app. Anytime I post an update through the app I get a popup error which says

```
"there was a problem with posting your status. we've logged the error and will look into it"
```

I tested it directly on my iphone.

Below is my FBManager singleton code:

FBManager.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>

@interface FBManager : NSObject{

 }

+(instancetype)sharedFBManager;
- (void)postUpdateWithShareDialog;
@end
```

FBManager.m

```
#import "FBManager.h"

@implementation FBManager

+(instancetype)sharedFBManager
{
    static FBManager *fbManager;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
       fbManager = [[self alloc]init];
    });

    return fbManager;
}

-(instancetype)init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        NSLog(@"Facebook manager created");

   }
   return  self;
}

- (void)postUpdateWithShareDialog {

    // Check if the Facebook app is installed and we can present the share dialog

    FBLinkShareParams *params = [[FBLinkShareParams alloc] init];
    params.link = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share/"];

    // If the Facebook app is installed and we can present the share dialog
    if ([FBDialogs canPresentShareDialogWithParams:params]) {

        // Present share dialog
        [FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithLink:nil
                                  handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error)     {
                                      if(error) {
                                          // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
                                          // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
                                          NSLog(@"Error publishing story: %@", error.description);
                                      } else {
                                          // Success
                                          NSLog(@"result %@", results);
                                      }
                                  }];

    // If the Facebook app is NOT installed and we can't present the share dialog
} else {
    // FALLBACK: publish just a link using the Feed dialog
    // Show the feed dialog
    [FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:nil
                                           parameters:nil
                                              handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
                                                  if (error) {
                                                      // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
                                                      // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
                                                      NSLog(@"Error publishing story: %@", error.description);
                                                  } else {
                                                      if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
                                                          // User cancelled.
                                                          NSLog(@"User cancelled.");
                                                      } else {
                                                          // Handle the publish feed callback
                                                          NSDictionary *urlParams = [self parseURLParams:[resultURL query]];

                                                          if (![urlParams valueForKey:@"post_id"]) {
                                                              // User cancelled.
                                                              NSLog(@"User cancelled.");

                                                          } else {
                                                              // User clicked the Share button
                                                              NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Posted story, id: %@", [urlParams valueForKey:@"post_id"]];
                                                              NSLog(@"result %@", result);
                                                          }
                                                      }
                                                  }
                                              }];
}
}

// A function for parsing URL parameters returned by the Feed Dialog.
- (NSDictionary*)parseURLParams:(NSString *)query {
    NSArray *pairs = [query componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    for (NSString *pair in pairs) {
        NSArray *kv = [pair componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
        NSString *val =
        [kv[1] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        params[kv[0]] = val;
    }
    return params;
}


@end
```

I tested it by calling the

```
- (void)postUpdateWithShareDialog;
```

method when a certain condition was satisfied. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: i am also faced same problem are  you giot the solution..@dcone